# Can I tell which ghc version a program was built with?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm wondering if there's a way to tell which ghc version a binary was built with. Major version is enough, specifically ghc 7 vs ghc 8.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/runtime_control.html#getting-information-about-the-rts), you can use the `--info` RTS flag:

```
$ ./a.out +RTS --info
[("GHC RTS", "YES")
,("GHC version", "6.7")
,("RTS way", "rts_p")
,("Host platform", "x86_64-unknown-linux")
,("Host architecture", "x86_64")
,("Host OS", "linux")
,("Host vendor", "unknown")
,("Build platform", "x86_64-unknown-linux")
,("Build architecture", "x86_64")
,("Build OS", "linux")
,("Build vendor", "unknown")
,("Target platform", "x86_64-unknown-linux")
,("Target architecture", "x86_64")
,("Target OS", "linux")
,("Target vendor", "unknown")
,("Word size", "64")
,("Compiler unregisterised", "NO")
,("Tables next to code", "YES")
]
```

Among other things, this lists the GHC version.

Comment: `"GHC version", "6.7"`.  6.7?  Have I gone back in time by a decade?  EDIT: Oh, it's a copy paste from the docs which were produced about 10 years ago, ok.

Comment: Is it possible to get this information from inside of a program (without inspecting it own binary)?

Comment: @PetrPudlák Use [`System.Info.compilerName/Version`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/System-Info.html#v:compilerVersion)